# Is it possible to add quantitative values to color legend in Vegalite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega, deneb

I'm currently trying to create a donut chart in Vega-lite that uses Royalty as theta and Year as color, and includes both values in the legend. The legend for color is working fine, but I cannot figure out how to either concatenate the theta values, or create a new legend.

I've tried hiding another arc underneath the current one and using Royalty as color, but Vega-lite connects the legends so you cannot control them individually.

I've tried creating a new text mark and moving it next to the legend, but the values stack as there is no x or y values. This way also feels wrong. I've gone over the documentation multiple times and I can't seem to find a solution.

Is there a way to do this?

[vega-editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAJpwkAJzQgATAAYbNxSABKbAJ47M7tAEY7AQEAvgqm5lbo9ja+zm6egt5+YoF2IWGW1lF2sR5ePqj2KUEAuiEgyBYA1mig3jhw1pZQIGVwslBsyjSyZDUg9HDqfQBmNHCCytZxec51DegAjgxIsph0ajSkLUodgmwRoKPjk+hmGUEXQA)

Comment: Something like: 2020 - 200000 | 2021 - 150000 | 2022 - 100000

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I think I'll go back to the drawing board for this one. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Chart]

Just concatenate the values in the Year field.

```
      {"Year": "2022 - 100000", "Royalty": 100000},
      {"Year": "2021 - 150000", "Royalty": 150000},
      {"Year": "2020 - 200000", "Royalty": 200000}
```

You could also create the label in DAX and pass it in as a separate column.

```
      {"Year": "2022", "Year label": "2022 - 100000", "Royalty": 100000},
      {"Year": "2021", "Year label": "2021 - 150000", "Royalty": 150000},
      {"Year": "2020", "Year label": "2020 - 200000", "Royalty": 200000}
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAJpwkAJzQgATAAYbNxSDOWABIKRM4g6-cdu-G4AjHZhYc4ASmwAnjqYMWih4XYAvgqm5lbo-sHOrhYeXj5+DsGBIWIpUbHxiajBVeHpmZal9vlZRd6+OQ52FfbVStFxggloQ80AuukgyBYA1migCThw1pZQIHNwslBsyjSyZCsg9HDqZwBmND7K1qN1zmsb6ACODEiymHRqNKQdkoDoI2NlQLd7tYCt0SkpfphBG8XF0gk9xolUligA)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of just concatenating the label in DAX! That worked, thank you!

Comment: I've learned a bunch of tricks like that from Kerry Kolosko's website. See https://kerrykolosko.com/category/custom-visualisations/deneb/. Her KPIs are out of this world amazing and has some great examples with images too.